# A layout like the tall layout, except that master area windows are in columns

Tags: xmonad

Is there a way to create a layout similar to a tall layout, except when you add more windows to the master pane, it orders them by columns rather than rows?

Comment: Do you mean by "adding to master area" that you press ``mod-,`` to increase the number of master windows?

Comment: @deshtop yes that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a definitive answer, but i use something similar for viewing PDF files, either one or two columns with slave on the right side (if there are slave windows).

```
import XMonad.Layout.ResizableTile
import XMonad.Layout.GridVariants
...
myPDFLayout = myPDFLayout1 ||| myPDFLayout2
myPDFLayout1 = ResizableTall 1 (3/100) (7/8) []
myPDFLayout2 = SplitGrid L 1 2 (7/8) (16/10) (3/100)
```

Feel free to add more columns - i guess `SplitGrid` can be used for three or more columns as well, find the details in [the documentation](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Layout-GridVariants.html).
If you don't know already check out the [xmonad contribs](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/), they provide quite a few different layouts, for example the two above.

Those layouts are per default changed  with `mod-Space`. You could rebind them  on specific workspaces like

```
((modMask, xK_comma), bindOn [("PDF", sendMessage NextLayout)])
```

but as far as i know there is nothing like `PrevLayout`, and it will cycle through the layouts rather then stopping.

edit: I thought there was a thread on SO about cycling backwards, [but i was wrong](http://www.reddit.com/r/xmonad/comments/17klpk/how_to_cycle_backwards_through_layouts/) (haven't read or tested this though)

Comment: Thanks I'll mark your answer as correct for the time being since I couldn't find any layout that can do the job now.  I went with something like:
"tiled = Tall 1 (1/16) (1/2)" and "grid = SplitGrid XMonad.Layout.GridVariants.L 1 2 (3/4) (16/9) (1/16)"
because I primarily use either 1 or 2 windows in the master pane (with any number of slaves).  Hopefully someone makes this one day :-).